# How to set a model's position using /gazebo/set_model_state service in python

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to set a model's position to origin after each measure loop, so that I can make automatically several measurements in the same conditions.

The `/gazebo/set_model_state` service enables us to transport the model to set position. How do I use it in python node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22125/how-to-set-a-model%27s-position-using-/gazebo/set_model_state-service-in-python/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The code below shows a node written in python, that will set the `my_robot`'s position to the origin of the map. The service requires a message of type `gazebo_msgs::ModelState`.

```
import rospy 
import rospkg 
from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelState 
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SetModelState

def main():
    rospy.init_node('set_pose')

    state_msg = ModelState()
    state_msg.model_name = 'my_robot'
    state_msg.pose.position.x = 0
    state_msg.pose.position.y = 0
    state_msg.pose.position.z = 0.3
    state_msg.pose.orientation.x = 0
    state_msg.pose.orientation.y = 0
    state_msg.pose.orientation.z = 0
    state_msg.pose.orientation.w = 0

    rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/set_model_state')
    try:
        set_state = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/set_model_state', SetModelState)
        resp = set_state( state_msg )

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s" % e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1